# Is the distinction between qualitative and quantitative methodology still significant today?

Tags: research-process, methodology, social-science

Some scholarly articles explain in detail the epistemological and ontological differences of the two methods, while some argue that the distinction between them is now blurred. I try to reconcile this inconsistency by thinking that quantitative and qualitative traditions form a methodological spectrum, where pure quantitative and qualitative approaches are situated at the opposing extremes, while mixed-methods are at the middle.

**Is the distinction between the research traditions still significant? And if yes, do social scientists promote a "methodological spectrum" or do they still deny the compatibility of the two?**

Comment: I am not happy with the wording of the question, but I think it can be easily answered: A closer look at for example sociological associations reveals that the differentiation is still relevant: [ASA methodology section](http://www.asanet.org/sections/methodology.cfm) deals only with quantitative methods and [ESA](http://www.europeansociology.org/research-networks-menu.html) has separated research networks for qualitative and quantitative mehtods. Despite the establishment of [mixed methods research](http://mmr.sagepub.com/), there are still crucial divides between epistemic communities.

Answer (score 0):

In nearly *every* scientific field you will find that some investigations are more heavily quantitative while others are quite qualitative in nature.  I find that the difference tends to be that qualitative investigations are more exploratory, observing a phenomenon in its natural conditions to establish that it really exists or to gather case-study sorts of information, while quantitative investigations are more aiming at firmly establishing an explanatory model.  The boundaries, however, are quite incremental and blurry, and I'm not quite sure what the value is of trying to draw a distinction, rather than simply saying: "this is the mixture of methods that can best study these phenomena at present."

Thus, while I don't know what the current vogue in theory of science is, I would be startled if it did not include a spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find today that more and more social scientists are using 'mixed methods.'

As for your question about the significance in difference, I think this is rather subjective and dependent on the school/field. In sociology for example, health research has a tendency to be more involved with stats and quantitative methods, while research in gender has a tendency to be much more qualitative.

As jakebeal suggests, no method is superior to the other, it really depends on what you are looking for and various methods will be ideal for various phenomena.

Personally, I am a firm believer in mixed methods, especially when exploring social issues. I find that purely quantitative approaches only give the numbers, but don't adequately explain the reasoning behind said numbers nor provide enough direction in how these numbers can be rectified. Adding in that qualitative aspect can be helpful to provide a much more rounded and holistic account of what's occurring.